# OkHttp http calls work in Java Main, but when I work with android app crashes

Tags: java, android, json, gson, okhttp

I'm currently working on an android project that retrieves `JSON` data from Riot API and parse it.

I'm using `OkHttp` to get the URL and convert the contents into a string, and then convert into Java Object using `GSON`. When I run my code in Java's main method, it works perfectly. However, when I'm using Android and run the code on an android phone, the app crashes. 
The error I get is

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference"

Here are my codes:

This is Android's `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String value = text.getText().toString();
    if (value.equals("")) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence tex = "Field cannot be empty!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, tex, duration);
        toast.show();
      } else {
        Summoner.getInstance().setSummonerName(value);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplaySummonerInfo.class);
        startActivity(i);
      }
}
}
```

This is the activity I jump to when user inputs a name

```
public class DisplaySummonerInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_summoner);
    GetSummonerID.getUserInfo();
    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    TextView id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    TextView level = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    name.setText(Summoner.getInstance().getSummonerName());
    id.setText(Summoner.getInstance().getSummonerID());
    level.setText(Summoner.getInstance().getSummonerLevel());
}
```

.This class converts data using `OkHttp` and `GSON`

```
public class GetSummonerID {

private static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public static String getJSON(String url) throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}

public static void getUserInfo(){
    String json = null;
    try {
        String url = "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/" + Summoner.getInstance().getSummonerName()
                + "?api_key=" + Summoner.getInstance().getApiKey();
        json = getJSON(url);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    SummID summID = gson.fromJson(json, SummID.class);

    Summoner.getInstance().setSummonerName(summID.getName());
    Summoner.getInstance().setSummonerID(summID.getId());
    Summoner.getInstance().setSummonerLevel(summID.getSummonerLevel());
}
```

Thank you in advanced for you help!

Comment: It was not in main Thread.

Comment: Could you show detail Log?And I will know that where caused the problem.

Comment: Just use Retrofit if you are going to combine OkHttp with Gson

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help! I actually solved the problem by using OkHttp's async method and now it works XD